# How , with iptables, to block access to docker container port from internet?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, iptables

How to block access to docker container port from the outer internet, by iptables?
ubuntu 18
I have remote server, in the server docker containers, i can access that docker container with $MY_SERVER_IP:$docker_container_port.
How to disable access to this container from internet and only allow for local calls within this server ?

Here is `iptables -L -n` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  -- !142.93.231.42        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  -- !127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:4466
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8000
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4467
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -D DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
iptables -A DOCKER-USER  -j DROP
iptables -I DOCKER-USER  -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER  -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER  -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER  -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j RETURN
```